# MYSQL, Event not running

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to run the MYSQL event at a particular time, and to be repeated after 24 hours:

```
ALTER EVENT myeventToronto1
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 24 HOUR
    STARTS '2013-08-04 02:02:00'

   COMMENT 'A sample comment.'
    DO

      INSERT into `smallworksdb`.`eventtesttable`(ID,NAME) Values(1,'someValue');
```

When I save the above event, the table is not getting populated at a particular time specified in the event, so I am assuming that the event does not get run.
What am I missing here.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do I have this string feeling that `id` is declared as a primary key (or at least `unique`)? And you are trying to insert the same value every day.  The problem would be an error generated by SQL, not that the job is not running.

Typically a field like `id` would be an auto_increment value that would be set automatically on insert, and not given a particular value.

This is just speculation.  There are other possibilities like the scheduler is turned off or the computer reboots at exactly that time every day?